# Origin point moves every time I try to select an object

Tags: 3d-cursor, origin

I must have messed up either the 3D cursor or the origin point, as every time I try to click and select, to move the object or rescale, the origin point moves along with my mouse wherever I click?

Comment: in the top right of your 3D view > Options > disable Affect Only > Origins

Comment: Here's how to take screenshots https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/mac.html since the ptoto isn't quite readable. For your question, maybe try to change pivot point by pressing dot on the keyboard > choose Median Point there. If it doesn't help [edit] the question with more screenshots of the problem

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you're using the **Cursor tool** (red) instead of the **Select Box tool** (green). Switch to that one and let me know if everything works.

[image]

---

Note that the 3D cursor and the Origin of an object are different things.

The 3D cursor determines the point in which objects are created in the 3D environment. Read:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html?highlight=cursor

The Origin of an object is the pivot point where the object rotates.
Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html?highlight=origin